# Is Euro Airlines legit?

Tags: uk, air-travel, bookings, airlines, cuba

Trying to track down more information about rumours of a [new direct flight](https://www.travelgossip.co.uk/latestnews/direct-flights-between-uk-and-cuba-could-be-reinstated-within-weeks/) between the UK and Cuba (Manchester >Holguin), which is supposedly to be operated by Spanish company Euro Airlines (EA).

I can find the inaugural flight on search aggregator sites like [Alternative Airlines](https://www.alternativeairlines.com/) and [Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/manc/hog/240510/240531/?adultsv2=1&cabinclass=economy&childrenv2=&ref=home&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false) but nothing at all on [EA’s website](https://www.euroairlines.es/).

I’ve never encountered this situation before. Can anyone explain what’s going on?

Comment: EA looks to be nothing more than a GDS provider/travel agency consulting firm, the only mention of an airline is through general aviation charter business. I doubt it is actually a commercial airline or a charter airline.

Comment: It's really weird, because IATA says their code is Q4 (not a controlled duplicate), but other sources say Q4 is Starlink Aviation (small airline operating very small aircraft in Canada) or even Swazi Express Airways (defunct). FR24 has a weird mix of both...

Answer (score 1):

I found another [page](https://www.euroairlines.es/euroairlines-anuncia-acuerdo-de-distribucion-con-cubana-de-aviacion/) on their website that discusses these flights:

> Actualmente, la compañía ofrece vuelos entre Madrid y Santiago de Cuba
> – La Habana todos los martes hasta el 24 de octubre. Además, la
> operación de retorno, hasta del 26 de abril, se operará todos los
> martes, mientras que desde el 4 de mayo se operará los jueves.

From google translate:

> Currently, the company offers flights between Madrid and Santiago de
> Cuba – Havana every Tuesday until October 24. In addition, the return
> operation, until April 26, will be operated every Tuesday, while from
> May 4 it will be operated on Thursdays.

And also:

> Igualmente, la compañía ofrecerá vuelos entre La Habana y Barcelona
> desde el 29 de junio todos los jueves, con frecuencia de ida y vuelta.
> Cubana de aviación se une a la red de aerolíneas que comercializa la
> plataforma Eurodistribution en más de 60 mercados a través de su placa
> Iata Q4-291. Las agencias de viajes iata pueden emitir a través de los
> principales GDS: Amadeus, Sabre y Travelport.

Translated:

> Likewise, the company will offer flights between Havana and Barcelona
> from June 29 every Thursday, with round trip frequency. Cubana de
> aviation joins the network of airlines that sells the Eurodistribution
> platform in more than 60 markets through its Iata Q4-291 plate. Iata
> travel agencies can issue through the main GDSs: Amadeus, Saber and
> Travelport.

From reading that and more, it looks like that they are code sharing with Cubana

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, the Iberojet Madrid>Santiago route was axed due to low profitability but Thomas Cook and Condor used to fly direct from Manchester to Holguin so maybe it’s spotted a gap in the market. Wouldn’r want to [fly Cubana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubana_de_Aviaci%C3%B3n_accidents_and_incidents) though :-(